Rear Trunk Water Leak
My car was rear ended few years back and since then have had some sort of leak in the trunk/boot. This leads to the end of the carpet on top of the reserve tyre getting wet as well as a section of both the back sides of the trunk (carpet). Thankfully there is no mould.
I tried to fix any potential leaks by first identifying the area, by pouring water on top of the trunk door and into the seams. After seeing a small leak near one of the indicators so patched it up using Sikaflex along with many other gaps just to be safe.
The issue however still seems to remain, I am therefore thinking of stripping it out again and basically applying a plastic sheet cover secured using Sikaflex or similar under the carpet trimmings as one piece, so the water stays under it and not soak the carpet.
Is putting a plastic sheet under likely to now introduce mould by essentially 'trapping' the water?
Any other potential fixes or methods I should look at?

Trunk leaks are difficult to find sometimes.  Putting plastic in there is a bad idea in my opinion. First, water always finds a way out or around. Second, even if you could trap it, then you have trapped water in there which is never good.
Temporarily, I'd remove the carpet and open the drain plugs to let the water out. Make sure you open the plug{s} under the spare tire.
For a permanent fix, you need to find the leak.  Get a friend to spray all around the trunk with a garden hose while you are inside there with a light.
Spray the trunk seal, rear window, brake lights, wheel wells, everywhere.  It doesn't take a big leak to have a water problem.
